# VBA Access - Create Excel Active X Object Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am facing a strange situation with my MS Access VBA Code.  I have a form with several buttons for importing data into tables coming from different Excel files.

In the form, 2 buttons have to open the same Excel workbook but different sheets.  In order to do this, I called the following subroutine in one of the buttons:

```
Sub solar_solar(showNotification As Boolean)

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim eexWB As Workbook
    Dim updatedDates As String
    Dim insertedDates As String

    On Error GoTo errorHandling

    ' open excel application and source file
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set eexWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(c_sourceFile_solar, False, True)

    ' update records
    updatedDates = updateWindOrSolarRecords(eexWB, cWindSheet, cStartRowWind, cStartColWind, c_sql_WindTable)
    ' more code ...
End Sub
```

The other subroutine (wind_wind) has exactly the same code for opening the excel file.  The solar_solar subroutine runs just fine but when then I try to run the second one, the code does not start executing and I get the alert: "*Object library feature not supported*" (Fehler beim Kompilieren: Funktionsmerkmal der Objektbibliothek nicht unerstützt) and points to the line:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

This occurs in Windows 7 MS Access 2002.  I do not understand how it is possible for this code to run well in one subroutine and not in another, when it is practically the same.  Has anyone experienced something similar? Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get more information about the problem by temporarily changing `xlApp.Visible = True` and `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True` in `solar_solar`?

Comment: Is `On Error GoTo errorHandling` the same in both Subs? Try changing the label to something unique for each Sub. (e.g. solar_solar_error: and wind_wind_error:)

Comment: Hi @HansUp - No, I can not get more information about the problem on those lines.

Comment: Hi @Constablebrew - each subroutine has its own errorHandling.  Maybe I wrongly assumed the scope of such definitions is the subroutine? Both subroutines are in the same Module, but if I put them in different modules then they work.  It is strange since I tried the code on a Windows XP machine with Access 2000 and it is working even though the subs are in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line labels may only occur once in each module as line label scope is the module level. You need to make sure every single line label is unique within any given module.

Currently you have something like this:

```
Sub solar_solar(showNotification As Boolean)
  On Error GoTo errorHandling
  '...
  errorHandling:
  '...
End Sub

Sub wind_wind(showNotification As Boolean)
  On Error GoTo errorHandling
  '...
  errorHandling: 'This is bad!
  '...
End Sub
```

Change the line labels and goto statements to be like the following:

`
    Sub solar_solar(showNotification As Boolean)
      On Error GoTo solar_errorHandling
      '...
      solar_errorHandling:
      '...
    End Sub

```
Sub wind_wind(showNotification As Boolean)
  On Error GoTo wind_errorHandling
  '...
  wind_errorHandling:
  '...
End Sub
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78335